# SQL Server 2014 Memory Optimized Table Type

Tags: t-sql, memory-optimized-tables

Just installed SQL Server 2014.

Syntax straight from the documentation fails.

This fails on `Sales`:

```
CREATE TYPE [Sales].[SalesOrderDetailType_inmem] AS TABLE(
  [OrderQty] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [SpecialOfferID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [LocalID] [int] NOT NULL,

  INDEX [IX_ProductID] HASH ([ProductID]) WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 8),
  INDEX [IX_SpecialOfferID] NONCLUSTERED 
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )
```

But if I remove `Sales` it still fails

```
CREATE TYPE [SalesOrderDetailType_inmem] AS TABLE(
  [OrderQty] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [SpecialOfferID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [LocalID] [int] NOT NULL,

  INDEX [IX_ProductID] HASH ([ProductID]) WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 8),
  INDEX [IX_SpecialOfferID] NONCLUSTERED 
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )
```

With the following error

> Msg 8135, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
>   Table level constraint does not specify column list, table 'SalesOrderDetailType_inmem'.

How to create a memory optimize table type?

Comment: The memory optimized table type was NOT faster than the existing #temp. The query went from 8 seconds to 10.  And this seemed like a prime candidate for MEMORY_OPTIMIZED table type.  The two table types are loaded with 800,000 rows and I sized the bucket at 2,000,000.

Comment: Have done some performance testing and the in-mem objects are unimpressive. I'm led to believe that they shine under high concurrent load though.

Comment: @MarkD I am hoping this is because still should not use table type for a lot of rows.  I have regular table I am converting over.  Hoping to see and improvement there.

Comment: I think you will be disappointed. It is possible though that they may perform well in the case of natively compiled procs - this is something I have yet to test.

Comment: I think people get edgy about conversations in comment? Have opened a chat room - first time, hope I am doing it right.

Comment: @MarkD Agree but I cannot make a chat work either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52615/discussion-between-markd-and-blam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax seems to work. I've scripted for the `dbo` schema. It is recommended that the `BUCKET_COUNT` is set to ~1x-2x the unique values that will be held.

```
CREATE TYPE [SalesOrderDetailType_inmem] AS TABLE(
  [OrderQty] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL 
    INDEX [IX_ProductID] HASH ([ProductID]) WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 8),
  [SpecialOfferID] [int] NOT NULL 
    INDEX [IX_SpecialOfferID] NONCLUSTERED ,
  [LocalID] [int] NOT NULL

)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )
```